# How to create a method that returns a value by default but also has an extension method?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

We can create something as simple as:

```
getName() { return 'My Name';}
```

And a method that returns an object with more methods like:

```
getName() {
    var name = 'My Name';
    return {
        raw: function() { return name; }
        decorate: function() { return '・°☆.。' + name + '.☆*・°☆'; }
    };
}
```

How do you combine the two ideas where if the a method is called as `getName()`, it returns a string. And at the same time you can still invoke its methods like `getName().decorate()` (or `getName.decorate()` ?) just like extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're passing in an argument it uses to decide to return one thing or theother, you can't make `getName` return something that's both a string **and** a non-String object. You can get *close*, but not all that close, by returning an object with a `toString` method that returns the string (you might also provide `valueOf`):

```js
function getName() {
    var name = 'My Name';
    return {
        toString() { return name; },
        valueOf() { return name; },
        decorate() { return '・°☆.。' + name + '.☆*・°☆'; }
    };
}

console.log(String(getName()));
console.log("The name is: " + getName());
console.log(getName());
console.log(getName().decorate());
```

But remember that it **always** returns an object. `toString` is triggered when something tries to convert that object to a primitive with the hint "string". `valueOf` is triggered when something tries to convert that object to a primitive with hint "number". (In both cases, if the first method is unavailable or it returns an object, the other method is called; [details in the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive).)

Comment: This is great! Is this the closest possible way? the third `console.log` as expected from your explanation returns the whole object.

Comment: @ColdCerberus - This is as close as you can get, yes.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is to pass something as parameter to call first or second, you choose.

```js
decorate = (name) =>
{
   console.log('・°☆.。' + name + '.☆*・°☆');
   return '・°☆.。' + name + '.☆*・°☆';
}
    
raw = (name) =>
{
   console.log(name);
   return name;
}
    
getName = (option) =>
{
   var name = 'Name';
   if (!option) { //default
     console.log(name + " Whatsup");
     return name + " Whatsup";
   }
   return (option === 'decorate' ? decorate(name) : raw(name));
}
    
getName();
```